# How to change a single datagrid row FontWeights to Bold?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

When a row is selected in my datagrid and a button is pressed, I want to change the FontWeight of the cells in that row to bold.

I've been looking for a way to do it, but all I can do is change the style of every columns, I can't find a way to get the selected row (or any rows for that matter).

There are no specific values that I can bind to from the ItemSource type, so a solution using XAML and a ValueConverter is unwanted due to the increased complexity. That is, unless it's the only way.

This is how I'm proceeding:

```
 <DataGrid Name="dgSessions" Width="200" Height="100" 
                          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                          HeadersVisibility="None" GridLinesVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          SelectionMode="Single" Background="White">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Style.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                                        Value="Normal"/>
                            </Style.Setters>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
  </DataGrid>


        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Style oldStyle = dgSessions.SelectedCells.First().Column.CellStyle;
        Setter setter = null;
        foreach (Setter item in oldStyle.Setters)
        {
            if (item.Property.Name == "FontWeight")
            {
                setter = new Setter(item.Property, FontWeights.Bold, item.TargetName);
                break;
            }
        }
        Style newStyle = new Style(oldStyle.TargetType);
        newStyle.Setters.Add(setter);
        dgSessions.SelectedCells.First().Column.CellStyle = newStyle;


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, you can get a row of a datagrid like that:

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(myIndex);
```

There is also a different method to get a row from an Item.

So I did the following to set the row I want in bold:

1. Retrieve the index with `int index = myObservableCollection.IndexOf(myObject)`
   I don't think the index is always valid if you have a lot of rows
   and virtualization is enabled, but given my context, it's fine.
2. Create my Setter

   ```
   Setter bold = new Setter(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold, null);
   ```
3. Get my row:

   ```
   DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dgSessions.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
   ```
4. Create Style and set it:

   ```
       Style newStyle = new Style(row.GetType());

       newStyle.Setters.Add(bold);
       row.Style = newStyle;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can define the `DataGridRow` style as below and on button click set the property to trigger a notification to apply the `FontWeight` on the Row

```
<Style x:Key="MyRowStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsProcessed}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The DataGrid will be defined as

```
<DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource MyRowStyle}" ...... />
```

Now to integrate it, you have to define property in the model which is bound to `ItemSource` of `DataGrid` (The model should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface). On button click, set the property defined in model and bound in `DataTrigger`

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var dataContext = btnConnect.DataContext as <<Your Model>>;
     dataContext.IsProcessed = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the concept of "model". I have an ObservableCollection (the itemsSource of my datagrid) of Session (my own class) where the column of the datagrid bind to the Name property of Session.

Comment: model here is your created class

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I tried add a bool Property "IsProcessed" to my model and I implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Although, it's kind of weird considering it is an immutable struct. My button is just a single button on my Window and it doesn't have a dataContext so I did the following:                `Session s = (Session)dgSessions.SelectedItem;
            s.IsProcessed = true;` but nothing changed.