# How to make a row bold in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid containing four rows, and I would need to make the texts in the last row bold, in order to better separate them from the rows above.

I tried the methods available in the question [How to change a single datagrid row FontWeights to Bold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729167/how-to-change-a-single-datagrid-row-fontweights-to-bold), but I was unable to get it working.

This is the code that I tried; running it results in an error, as `row` is null.

```
Setter bold = new Setter(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold, null);
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)DG_PPC.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(3);
Style newStyle = new Style(row.GetType());
newStyle.Setters.Add(bold);
row.Style = newStyle;
```

I would appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you!

XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG_PPC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="115" Margin="661,-6,0,0"
HeadersVisibility="Column" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="726.25"
Loaded="DataGrid_PPC_Loaded" RowHeaderWidth="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" FontSize="12" IsReadOnly="True">
```

Comment: It depends when do you run this part of code.

Comment: This code works for me. Provide an MCVE where it doesn't work.

Comment: Add some more code along with the question so we can see what your doing wrong.

Comment: The code works for me also, when I assign it to a separate button for example. But I would like to get it automatically working, once the `DataGrid` is filled with values. In my method, after filling the `DataGrid`, it is refreshed using `DG_PPC.Items.Refresh();` - if I try to use the same code here, immediately after the refresh, the `row` is always null. Perhaps I need to place the "bolding code" to some other, `DataGrid` related method? (Though I have no idea where.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself another way to do it, which is compatible with my code. Here's the solution, in case someone will be needing something similar.

**APP.XML:**

```
<Application.Resources>
  <local:FontWeightConverter x:Key="FontWeightConverter"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
      Path=Item.XYZ, Converter={StaticResource FontWeightConverter}}"/>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

**Code:**

```
class FontWeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string name = (string)value;
        if (name.Equals("Δ"))
            return FontWeights.Bold;
        else
            return FontWeights.Normal;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```