# Make 0th column in the datagrid bold

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am binding a datatable to the datagrid with AutoGenerateColumns set to true. Now I want make the text in the 0th column to be bold. How can I do it. Please help. I was referring to this post [change single row to bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729167/how-to-change-a-single-datagrid-row-fontweights-to-bold) but it shows how to get the row but I want to get the 0th column. I can do something like this, but it changes the font for all the cells. I only want the 0th column bold.

```
 <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Style.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                                        Value="Bold"/>
                            </Style.Setters>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

xaml

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="*" FontSize="16" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HeadersVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding RunViewModel.RunInfoDataTable}" >
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="28"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this.

Specify each column binding and then set your style to the respective column.

And also use column style ex:`DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle`

Some what like below:

```
<DataGrid ........................>

  <DataGrid.Columns>
      <!--COLUMN1-->
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding columnone}">
            <!--SET YOUR COLUMN SPECIFIC STYLE HERE.-->
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Style.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                                        Value="Bold"/>
                            </Style.Setters>
                 </Style>
             </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>

      </DataGridTextColumn>

      <!--COLUMN2-->
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding columntwo}">
      </DataGridTextColumn>

      <!--COLUMN3-->
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding columnthree}">
      </DataGridTextColumn>

  </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Ok let me try. In that case I need to Set AutoGenerateColumns to false and bind each column separately from datatable.

Comment: yes. Then you will have fine grained control over your individual column styles.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="HEADER_NAME" Width="40" FontWeight="Bold" Binding="{Binding COLUMN_NAME}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource WrapText}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

You can simply add **"FontWeight="Bold"** to your DataGridTextColumn.